# Change Button Style at Runtime in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I have a Button in Silverlight. I need to change its style at runtime. The style of this Button needs to change multiple times during the life of the application. Is this possible in Silverlight? If not, what is a good workaround?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [`VisualStateManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to change the state of the button as appropriate.

You could create your own states for each of the different styles you wish to show.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but I'd think hard about what exactly you're trying to do by changing the style itself because there's probably an easier way.  You've probably already run into the fact that you can't simply assign a new style to the button with something like `MyButton.Style = (Style)FindName("NewButtonStyle")`.  So you do need some kind of alternative.

The VisualStateManager is the first and easiest way of handling most kinds of changes that you would normally want to do to a control.  You can pretty easily set changes to occur on the normal sorts of visible states (hover, focus, mousedown, mouseup) and it'll animate those state changes correctly from whatever state you're in to whatever other state you need.

If the kind of change you're looking for is more extensive, changing the type of control to, say, a ContentControl and then catching the mousedown/mouseup events from there might be a better workaround.  This is obviously a bigger deal (and you lose the simplicity of having a button), but you'd be able to get whatever changes you wanted to pretty easily by just swapping out the Content property.

Somewhere between the two (and something I'll mention because it's possible, not because I recommend it) would be to actually manipulate the Style definition itself.  The Button will pick up the changes and adjust itself.  I'm going to repeat myself here though: I don't recommend this and I can't envision a scenario where I'd prefer doing this over using the VSM or using something other than a Button entirely.  But it is possible to get into `Application.Current.Resources["Style"] as Style` and muck about with whatever you please.  The bigger question then is why and whether what you're doing can be done some other way that would make more sense for whoever's going to maintain your code later.  Personally, I expect Styles to be pretty static and I think that's the general consensus too.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can....

if you have a style stored locally you can access it like that :

```
rec1.Style = (Style)this.Resources["style1"];
```